# How do I run the Ethereum Wallet software on a private chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I have read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/how-to-run-ethereum-wallet-on-a-custom-chain) post over and over again, but I can't wrap my head around the answer.

I too have downloaded the Ethereum Wallet, but want to test some things separately from the main chain (I figured this is a must, as I don't have any ether, nor the CPU/GPU power to mine). So, I have also downloaded Command Line Tools (geth) and put geth.exe in C:\ (I'm on Windows 10). I execute the following as a simple test:

```
geth --datadir "C:\Test" --rcp
```

Which results in the `Test` dir being created and `localhost:8545` outputting:

```
{
   id: null,
   jsonrpc: "2.0",
   error: {
       code: -32600,
       message: "Could not decode request"
   }
}
```

Ethereum Wallet won't run because it can't start a node (there's already one running). Furthermore, I have no idea how to use `--ipcpath` seeing as it is not in the flags list for `geth`. Moreover, I have no idea how/where to implement the `genesis.json`, which I read about everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

**Console1:**

```
geth account new
geth --dev
```

**Console2:**

```
geth --dev attach
> miner.start()
```

This sets up a default genesis block.

Then open wallet.exe.

Comment: It says the `-dev` flag is not defined

Comment: ........`--dev`?

Comment: it's the output from the `geth --dev` command

Comment: what geth version?

Comment: Geth/v0.9.26/windows/go1.4.2

Comment: try updating -> latest is 1.4.13 I think

Comment: wow, you're right (which is weird because the latest.zip contained this one). With the new version your code works! awesome